how to replace zero with incremental value in in R data frame?
I have a dataset where I want to replace each zero with incrementing values: the first zero becomes 0.001, the second 0.002, the third 0.003, and so on. Each time a zero appears, it should increase by 0.001 from the previous replacement.
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(Year = 1981:2000, Value = sample(0:5, 20, replace = T))


You're are implicitly converting Value from integer to float.

library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  filter(Value != 0) %>% 
  rbind(.,
    DF %>% 
      filter(Value == 0) %>% 
      mutate(Value = cumsum(Value + .001))) %>% 
  arrange(Year)

   Year Value
1  1981 2.000
2  1982 5.000
3  1983 2.000
4  1984 1.000
5  1985 1.000
6  1986 5.000
7  1987 2.000
8  1988 4.000
9  1989 3.000
10 1990 5.000
11 1991 5.000
12 1992 0.001
13 1993 1.000
14 1994 2.000
15 1995 4.000
16 1996 2.000
17 1997 2.000
18 1998 0.002
19 1999 3.000
20 2000 0.003


Downvotes are helpful when accompanied by a reason; otherwise, they seem pointless, and it feels like the person downvoting is hiding behind anonymity.

I didn't downvote but the problem with this answer is that it uses DF within the pipeline and not just at the beginning.  Normally pipelines should go from left to right. Also it is more verbose than the other answers.

set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(Year = 1981:2000, Value = sample(0:5, 20, replace = T))

idx <- which(DF$Value == 0)
DF$Value[idx] <- seq_along(idx) * .001
DF
#>    Year Value
#> 1  1981 2.000
#> 2  1982 5.000
#> 3  1983 2.000
#> 4  1984 1.000
#> 5  1985 1.000
#> 6  1986 5.000
#> 7  1987 2.000
#> 8  1988 4.000
#> 9  1989 3.000
#> 10 1990 5.000
#> 11 1991 5.000
#> 12 1992 0.001
#> 13 1993 1.000
#> 14 1994 2.000
#> 15 1995 4.000
#> 16 1996 2.000
#> 17 1997 2.000
#> 18 1998 0.002
#> 19 1999 3.000
#> 20 2000 0.003

Created on 2024-11-12 with reprex v2.1.1

in dplyr:
DF%>%
  mutate(Value=if_else(Value==0,cumsum(Value==0)*0.001,Value))

equivalently in base R:
DF$Value <- with(DF,ifelse(Value==0,cumsum(Value==0)*0.001,Value))


We can do
# DF$Value = 
with(DF, { i = Value==0; replace(Value, i, .001 * cumsum(i)[i]) })

giving
 [1] 2.000 5.000 2.000 1.000 1.000 5.000 2.000 4.000 3.000
[10] 5.000 5.000 0.001 1.000 2.000 4.000 2.000 2.000 0.002
[19] 3.000 0.003


val <- DF$Value == 0

transform(DF, Value = replace(Value, val, (cumsum(val) * 0.001)[val]))
   Year Value
1  1981 2.000
2  1982 5.000
3  1983 2.000
4  1984 1.000
5  1985 1.000
6  1986 5.000
7  1987 2.000
8  1988 4.000
9  1989 3.000
10 1990 5.000
11 1991 5.000
12 1992 0.001
13 1993 1.000
14 1994 2.000
15 1995 4.000
16 1996 2.000
17 1997 2.000
18 1998 0.002
19 1999 3.000
20 2000 0.003


Given the vote, how can this post be improved? Now, don't tell me it's lacking a description...
